# ffmpeg-mp4box-mpeg dash plays only few segments

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, mpeg-dash

Need help in debugging the segment dash files

The input was an MP4 with these details. This was recorded from a video camera, the output from the camera was mkv and we converted into MP4 after editing the audio via adobe

- Size: 7.51 GB Frame rate: 25 frames/ second
- Data rate: 25326kbps
- Total bitrate: 25525kbps

Converted this to another mp4 with this command

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -b:v 750k -bf 2 -g 75 -sc_threshold 0 -an video_1280x720_750k.mp4

ffmpeg -i "input.mp4"  -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 96k -ar 32000 -vn audio_96k.mp4
```

The output video has

- fps: 25
- Data rate: 761kbps
- bitrate: 761kbps

Then, created the segmented dash through MP4Box

```
MP4Box -dash 10000 -frag 10000 -rap -segment-name video_0_1280000\segment_ video_1280x720_750k.mp4

MP4Box -dash 3000 -frag 10000 -rap -segment-name audio_0_96000\segment_ audio_96k.mp4
```

The MPD generated was validated online and its perfect

**UPDATE!** Included the MPD file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.5.2-DEV-rev621-g236c5f8-master  at 2015-10-26T05:16:19.619Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H2M0.000S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M10.000S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
  <Title>video_1280x720_500k_dash.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period duration="PT0H2M0.000S">
   <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" lang="eng">
     <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="32000" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="98434">
       <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
       <SegmentList timescale="32000" duration="319999">
         <Initialization sourceURL="audio_0_96000/segment_init.mp4"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_1.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_2.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_3.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_4.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_5.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_6.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_7.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_8.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_9.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_10.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_11.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_12.m4s"/>
         <SegmentURL media="audio_0_96000/segment_13.m4s"/>
       </SegmentList>
     </Representation>
   </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" maxFrameRate="25" par="16:9" lang="eng">
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc3.64001f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="25" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="764668">
    <SegmentList timescale="12800" duration="125866">
     <Initialization sourceURL="video_0_1280000/segment_init.mp4"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_1.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_2.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_3.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_4.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_5.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_6.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_7.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_8.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_9.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_10.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_11.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_12.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="video_0_1280000/segment_13.m4s"/>
    </SegmentList>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>

 </Period>
</MPD>
```

Played the video through dashjs.. I believe it just plays the initial segment and errors out as MEDIA_ERR_DECODE..MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED.. or some message which says **start** not found..

Through chrome debugging I see that atleast 4 segments are correctly loading.. I am not sure whats going on..

Any help in debugging the issue is really appreciated. **I really can't understand if this is a problem with the file or ffmpeg or mp4box or chrome**.

Output from chrome debugging tool

```
[dash.js 1.5.1] new MediaPlayer instance has been created 
dash.all.js:11 Playback initiated! 
dash.all.js:11 Parsing complete: ( xml2json: 5ms, objectiron: 10ms, total: 0.015s) 
dash.all.js:11 Manifest has been refreshed at Mon Oct 26 2015 10:19:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)[1445869162092]  
dash.all.js:11 SegmentTimeline detected using calculated Live Edge Time 
dash.all.js:11 MediaSource is open! 
dash.all.js:11 [object Event] 
dash.all.js:11 Duration successfully set to: 120 
dash.all.js:11 Added 0 inline events 
dash.all.js:11 video codec: video/mp4;codecs="avc3.64001f" 
dash.all.js:11 [video] stop 
dash.all.js:11 audio codec: audio/mp4;codecs="mp4a.40.2" 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] stop 
dash.all.js:11 No text data. 
dash.all.js:11 No fragmentedText data. 
dash.all.js:11 No muxed data. 
dash.all.js:11 [video] start 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 0 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] start 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 0 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 9.83328125 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 9.83328125 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 0 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 9.83328125 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 9.99996875 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 9.99996875 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 0 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 9.99996875 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 loaded audio:Media Segment:0 (200, 20ms, 6ms) 
dash.all.js:11 loaded video:Media Segment:0 (200, 153ms, 43ms) 
dash.all.js:11 loaded video:Initialization Segment:NaN (200, 0ms, 32ms) 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Initialization finished loading 
dash.all.js:11 loaded audio:Initialization Segment:NaN (200, 0ms, 34ms) 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Initialization finished loading 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 19.6665625 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 19.6665625 is 1 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 9.83328125 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 19.6665625 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 19.9999375 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 19.9999375 is 1 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 9.99996875 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 19.9999375 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Stalling Buffer 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Waiting for more buffer before starting playback. 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Stalling Buffer 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Waiting for more buffer before starting playback. 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 <video> loadedmetadata 
dash.all.js:11 Starting playback at offset: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 29.499843750000004 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 29.499843750000004 is 2 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 19.6665625 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 29.499843750000004 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Got enough buffer to start. 
dash.all.js:11 [video] seek: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 29.999906250000002 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 29.999906250000002 is 2 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 19.9999375 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 29.999906250000002 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Got enough buffer to start. 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] seek: 0 
dash.all.js:11 loaded audio:Media Segment:9.99996875 (200, 67ms, 24ms) 
dash.all.js:11 loaded video:Media Segment:9.83328125 (200, 71ms, 31ms) 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Buffered Range: 0.032 - 9.984 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 Start Event Controller 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Buffered Range: 0.032 - 19.999968 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 <video> play 
dash.all.js:11 [video] start 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 0 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 9.83328125 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 19.6665625 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] start 
dash.all.js:11 <video> playing 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Buffered Range: 0 - 9 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 Do seek: 0.032 
dash.all.js:11 <video> seek 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 29.499843750000004 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 29.499843750000004 is 2 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 19.6665625 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 29.499843750000004 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] seek: 0.032 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] seek: 0.032 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 9 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 9 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 0 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 9.83328125 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 19.6665625 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] SegmentList: 29.499843750000004 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Buffered Range: 0 - 18 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 loaded video:Media Segment:19.6665625 (200, 42ms, 33ms) 
dash.all.js:11 <video> seeked 
dash.all.js:11 Start Event Controller 
dash.all.js:11 <video> playing 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Buffered Range: 0 - 28 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [video] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 19.999968 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 19.999968 is 1 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 9.99996875 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 19.9999375 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 29.999906250000002 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 29.999906250000002 is 2 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 19.9999375 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] SegmentList: 29.999906250000002 / 120 
dash.all.js:11 loaded audio:Media Segment:19.9999375 (200, 102ms, 2ms) 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Buffered Range: 0.032 - 29.983968 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 loaded audio:Media Segment:29.999906250000002 (200, 26ms, 2ms) 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Buffered Range: 0.032 - 39.999968 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Getting the request for time: 0 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] Index for time 0 is 0 
dash.all.js:11 loaded video:Media Segment:29.499843750000004 (200, 47ms, 7ms) 
dash.all.js:11 Video Element Error: MEDIA_ERR_DECODE 
dash.all.js:11 [video] stop 
dash.all.js:11 [audio] stop 
dash.all.js:11 Video Element Error: MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED 
dash.all.js:11 <video> play
```

Comment: Can you post a sample mpd? What codec strings do you have in there? And how old is your ffmpeg?

Comment: ffmpeg is recent downloaded sometime on 10/12. However the same code works good for .MOV file recorded through my iphone. I was able successfully segment and play on dash.js and bitdash

Comment: @Andrew Included the MPD in the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried audio and video separately? This would at least isolate the error.

You can also try to encode your assets according to http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2014/11/mpeg-dash-content-generation-using-mp4box-and-x264/, which worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already encoded the audio and video separately. Now, the audio works fine and the issue is with only video. I tried the link which you mentioned but no luck. Any suggestion on how to debug the video part? I need to know possible reason for it to fail

Comment: Your idea to test the audio and video was the starting point.. I noted that I didn't have the option -bf -g option on the audio so I removed it from the video and everything worked suddenly.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a browser playback issue in regard to which codecs are supported by the browser.

Try adding the codec strings in here to see if they play: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_canplaytype

While avc3.64001f should play it may not in certain browsers and you could try main profile instead, try adding this to your ffmpeg command after the input file

```
-profile:v main
```